# ¿Cómo agregar una coma a un numero?

Tags: r

necesito transformar una de las columnas de mi dataframe de la siguiente forma (pondre una columna de ejemplo porque el dataframe es muy grande)

```
tiempo
8
12
102
34
101
81
25
76
```

lo que necesito es que si el numero es de un solo dígito, como el 8, pase a ser 8.0,  si tiene 2 como el 81, pase a ser 8.1,  si tiene tres como el 102, pase a ser 10.2, la idea es que siempre haya un decimal despues del punto, pero no se como hacer eso.

Comment: ¿qué tipo de dato es `tiempo`? agrega la salida de `str(tu_dataframe)`.

Comment: son todos numeros, str(cctp$DURACION_FORMAL)
 num [1:1452] 8 8 8 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 ... ese es el estracto de mi dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
x <- c(8, 78, 178)

ifelse(x < 10, x, x/10)
[1]  8.0  7.8 17.8
```

Con `ifelse()` si el valor es menor a 10, retornamos el valor, caso contrario dividimos por 10.